# html form is not recognizing inputs

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, input

I am trying to make a calculator where you press buttons and it outputs it in a textbox, which I will use its value with python to output an answer. However, when I submit it, the textbox is not even recognized as in the form. This is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript"">
function moveNumbers(num) {
var txt=document.getElementById("text").value;
if (num=="del"){ 
txt=txt.slice(0,-1)
}
else if (num=="clr"){
txt=""
}
else{   
txt=txt + num;}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="calc.py" method="POST" >
<textarea maxlength="492" disabled id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="td1"><button type="button"  class="number" name="number" value="2" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">2</button></td>

<td class="td1"><button type="button"  class="number" name="number" value="3" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">3</button></td>
<td class="td1"><input type="submit" class="number" value="="></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this is the error I get from python :

> /usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py in **getitem**(self=FieldStorage(None, None,
>   []), key='text') 539 if item.name == key: found.append(item) 540 if
>   not found: => 541 raise KeyError, key 542 if len(found) == 1: 543
>   return found[0] builtin KeyError = , key =
>   'text' : 'text' args = ('text',) message ='text'

Comment: this is the error i get from python
 /usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py in __getitem__(self=FieldStorage(None, None, []), key='text')
    539             if item.name == key: found.append(item)
    540         if not found:
=>  541             raise KeyError, key
    542         if len(found) == 1:
    543             return found[0]
builtin KeyError = <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, key = 'text'
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'text' 
      args = ('text',) 
      message = 'text'

Comment: Unsure why this needed to be downvoted.  Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 1):

The input with type submit will post the data. Is that what you need? I guess you should try using input type as button or use button tag.

Comment: Even if I change it that way I get the same error. For example, when I change the form to GET, and see what comes up in the website bar, there is nothing after the calc.py

Answer (score 1):

The disabled attribute on the textarea is preventing it from being submitted.

You could try one of the following:

a. Using the readonly attribute intead of disabled

```
<textarea maxlength="492" readonly="readonly" id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

b. Storing the numbers in an input of type hidden as well as the textarea

c. Enabling the textarea with javascript when submitting

Answer (score 1):

I think there is just one extra quote in your markup where you speciy script type as text/javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Notice the Extra Quote here in your code -->
function moveNumbers(num) {
var txt=document.getElementById("text").value;
if (num=="del"){ 
txt=txt.slice(0,-1)
}
else if (num=="clr"){
txt=""
}
else{   
txt=txt + num;}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="calc.py" method="POST" >
<textarea maxlength="492" disabled id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="td1"><button type="button"  class="number" name="number" value="2" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">2</button></td>

<td class="td1"><button type="button"  class="number" name="number" value="3" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">3</button></td>
<td class="td1"><input type="submit" class="number" value="="></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Hope this helps